# Account for simple url rewriting in ASP.NET MVC redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, routes

How would you go about redirecting in ASP.NET MVC to take into account some external URL rewriting rules.

For example:

- What the user enters: http://www.example.com/app/route
- What ASP.NET MVC sees: /route
- What I want to redirect to: http://www.example.com/app/other_route
- What actually happens when I do a simple [RedirectToAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460311.aspx): http://www.example.com/other_route (which doesn't exist, from the outside anyway)

This seems like it should be simple, but I'm drawing a blank.

Comment: I have two actions Index and Index2. In Index, I have RedirectToAction("index2"). When I request /home/Index I get taken to /home/Index2. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: @Raj Kaimal - roughly.  Its across different controllers, but that's really not important.  As it stands, with the rewriting turned off RedirectToAction works fine; I just need some way to say "put /app/ before the destination url" or equivalent.

Comment: ..and you need the route values or pass other data I assume? Which is why you are not using a simple redirect. Correct?

Comment: @Raj Kaimal - correct, data is being passed in the third parameter of RedirectToAction.

Comment: You make have to store it in Temp data and redirect. http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/01/23/37947/

Answer (score -1):

Just use

`RedirectToAction("NewAction", "Controller-Required-If-Diferent-From-Current-Controller");`